# Merge MeshRegion that is 'useless'

Tags: graphics3d, mesh, 3d-printing

Currently my 3D model have too many meshs/polygons. My model is simple, in the sense that it is only a Union of a box and a cylinder. But after `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`, the mesh count is ~2000.

Here's my model:

```
cube = Cuboid[] // Graphics3D // DiscretizeGraphics;
cylinder = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1] // Graphics3D // DiscretizeGraphics;
shape = RegionUnion[cube, cylinder] // BoundaryDiscretizeRegion
```

And the mesh count with `MeshCellCount[shape]` is:

```
{1444, 4326, 2884}
```

This is problematic when I export said model to `stl`. Is it possible to merge some of the useless mesh regions? For example the cube surface that is not connected to the cylinder can ideally be represented by a single mesh.

Comment: Since you use `RegionUnion` on `MeshRegion`, your Mathematica version is 11.2. Right ?

Comment: Why is problematic? resolution?, file size? manage the `.stl` model? Please, elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MaxCellMeasure`:

```
cube = Cuboid[];
cylinder = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1];
shape = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[cube, cylinder], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity]
```

[image]

```
MeshCellCount[shape]
{466, 1392, 928}
```

Comment: Is it possible to take the triangulation on the top of the cylinder and unwrap that into a coarser one? I'm picturing how I'd do this with SketchUp where I'd represent that with just two triangles (assuming triangulation).

Comment: @b3m2a1, not that I can think of.

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention that I tried to adjust the `MaxCellMeasure` parameter. I still think there are too many 'useless' triangles generated. For example the central top region should be combined into a single polygon, if possible.

Comment: But maybe this is the only possible way. Since it does make things better.